# Render double curly-brackets inside handlebars partial

Tags: handlebars.js

How do you force handlebars.js to ignore (and not render) templates?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's possible to escape the line with backslash

```
\{{>partialName}}
```

It's not mentioned in the documentation, but a look at the source-code documentation revealed this technique.

Comment: This is a convention in Handlebars and is the way we usually do it.

Comment: Yeah, this syntax is from Handlebars.js, the default template engine that Assemble uses.

Comment: You can use whitespace control: ${ {{~foo~}} test} (http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#whitespace-control)

Answer (score 2):

HTML entity might be a solution if you just wang to display your brackets. Try `&#123;` and `&#125;`.