# Handlebars.Net How to change behavior if data does not exist

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebars.net

In Handlebars.Net, if there is no matching field, it just places a blank there.

```
string source = @"My name is {{Name}} and I work at {{Job}}";
var template = Handlebars.Compile(source);
var data = new {
    Job = "Walmart"
};
var result = template(data);
```

Results in this because the `{{Name}}` is not in the data.

> My name is  and I work at Walmart

Is there a setting to say, just don't replace it if the data field does not exist?

I'd like for it to return:

> My name is {{Name}} and I work at Walmart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Supported in 1.x: use `UnresolvedBindingFormatter`

   `handlebars.Configuration.UnresolvedBindingFormatter = "('{0}' is undefined)";`
2. Supported starting from [2.0.0-preview-1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Handlebars.Net/2.0.0-preview-1): use [`helperMissing` hook](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/hooks.html#helpermissing)

   ```cs
   handlebars.RegisterHelper("helperMissing", (context, arguments) =>
   {
       var name = arguments.Last().ToString();
       return "{{" + name.Trim('[', ']') + "}}";
   });
   ```

For more details see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Handlebars-Net/Handlebars.Net/issues/373).

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to use an `#if`, as in:

`My name is {{#if Name}}{{Name}}{{else}}\{{Name}}{{/if}} and I work at {{Job}}`

Note: I owe thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22249597/3397771) for how to tell Handlebars to render the braces.

Answer (score 0):

For version Handlebars.Net Version="2.1.4".

```
var handlersTemplate = "My Name: {{Name}} Work {{Work}}";
var data = new { Work = "Remote" };
var result = CompileHandlebars(handlebarsTemplate,data);

private static string CompileHandlebars(string handlebarsTemplate, dynamic data)
{
    var handlebars = Handlebars.Create();
    var format = "{0}";
    handlebars.RegisterHelper("helperMissing",
        (in HelperOptions options, in Context context, in Arguments arguments) =>
        {
            return "{{" + string.Format(format, options.Name.TrimmedPath) + "}}";
        });

    var template = handlebars.Compile(handlebarsTemplate);
    return template(data);
}
```

Then end result would be:
result = "My Name: {{Name}} Work Remote";